# Converting mysql input before output. Unix timestamp to PHP DateTime

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm calling data from my database "_gameserver" and putting it into a php as follows. I understand it could be compiled easier and made shorter, but I'm still learning, and not there yet.

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASS";
$dbname = "_gameserver";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT _Key, _Data, _Name, _Ammo, _Cash, _Model, _Flags, _Faction, _SteamID, _SteamName, _Inventory, _LastPlayed, _TimeCreated FROM characters";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table style='border: solid 3px black;'>
<tr><th>Key</th>
<th>Steam ID</th>
<th>Steam Name</th>
<th>Last Played</th>
<th>Character Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Faction</th>
<th>Inventory</th>
<th>Loaded Ammo</th>
<th>Money</th>
<th>Character Model</th>
<th>Character Created</th>
<th>Char Flags</th></tr>";


$unix_timestamp = $_POST['_TimeCreated'];
$datetime = new DateTime("@$unix_timestamp");


// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Key"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_SteamID"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_SteamName"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_LastPlayed"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Name"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Data"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Faction"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Inventory"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Ammo"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Cash"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Model"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".date_create_from_format('U', $row["_TimeCreated"])->format('F j, Y, g:i a')"</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Flags"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

The "_LastPLayer" string that it grabs from the database is a unix timestamp, I want to convert it into something readable, and then output it with the rest of the data.

I've found what looks like a usable piece of code:

```
$unix_timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
$datetime = new DateTime("@$unix_timestamp");
```

And I've searched around, but I just cannot figure out how to fit it all together, please help.

Comment: With your `DateTime` object, you can call the `format` method, eg `echo $datetime->format('r');`. See http://php.net/manual/datetime.format.php

Comment: Thank you Phil, I appreciate the input, however that simply displays it out of place, not in the $row with the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that value is in `$row["_TimeCreated"]`

You can use [create_from_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php)

```
<td>".date_create_from_format('U', $row["_TimeCreated"])->format('F j, Y, g:i a')."</td>
```

or

```
<td>".DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $row["_TimeCreated"])->format('F j, Y, g:i a')."</td>
```

*alternatively*, you can use [date_create()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) and [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

```
<td>".date_create('@'.$row["_TimeCreated"])->format('F j, Y, g:i a')."</td>
```

or

```
<td>".(new DateTime('@'.$row["_TimeCreated"]))->format('F j, Y, g:i a')."</td>
```

Result will be the same: https://3v4l.org/u6EuR.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the alternative methods! I really appreciate the examples.
I seem to be running into an issue that I haven't seen yet, and don't understand it either.

    `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" '     (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/www    /*****/public/charsheets/CharSheets1.php on line 50`

Comment: No probs. The error your showing there is not in your code, can you update your question with the code `CharSheets1.php` on line 49. I think you missed the ending `;`

Comment: I thought so too, so I played around with adding and removing the ends on 49 and 50, but no luck. Updated the Q's Code. Everything seems properly closed off

Comment: Yup, your missing a `.` `->format('F j, Y, g:i a')HERE"</td>`

Comment: Those pesky periods! Thank you. And now of course it doesn't like the code that I found to convert the unix timestamp! `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character in /usr/www/*****/public/charsheets/CharSheets1.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /usr/www/******/public/charsheets/CharSheets1.php(34): DateTime->__construct('@') #1 {main} thrown in /usr/www/*****/public/charsheets/CharSheets1.php on line 34`

Comment: Remove the test code `$unix_timestamp = $_POST['_TimeCreated'];
$datetime = new DateTime("@$unix_timestamp"); ` as i suspect `$_POST['_TimeCreated']` is empty so its just passing @ which is wrong.

Comment: I figured that out seconds before you posted, haha. Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Finished product, works like a charm! Outputs the unix formatted date into something readable!

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASS";
$dbname = "_gameserver";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT _Key, _Data, _Name, _Ammo, _Cash, _Model, _Flags, _Faction, _SteamID, _SteamName, _Inventory, _LastPlayed, _TimeCreated FROM characters";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table style='border: solid 3px black;'>
<tr><th>Key</th>
<th>Steam ID</th>
<th>Steam Name</th>
<th>Last Played</th>
<th>Character Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Faction</th>
<th>Inventory</th>
<th>Loaded Ammo</th>
<th>Money</th>
<th>Character Model</th>
<th>Character Created</th>
<th>Char Flags</th></tr>";



// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Key"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_SteamID"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_SteamName"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_LastPlayed"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Name"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Data"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Faction"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Inventory"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Ammo"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Cash"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Model"]."</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".date_create_from_format('U', $row["_TimeCreated"])->format('F j, Y, g:i a')"</td>
<td style='width:150px;border:3px solid black;'>".$row["_Flags"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```